# Maven archetype plugin - Checksum validation warnings

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-archetype

I am using Maven 3.5 on Windows 7.
The Environment variables 'M2_HOME' and 'JAVA_HOME' are set correctly, and 'JAVA_HOME\bin' and 'M2_HOME\bin' are included in my system's PATH.

I deleted all the files under .m2 directory and executed from the command line:

**$mvn archetype:generate -DinteractiveMode=true**

Maven downloaded some files successfully until the following was displayed:

```
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/maven-archetype/2.2/maven-archetype-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected d5572e8bea6f4876a086779ea878d71731d0ab36 but is 0d9d945a1b1c11a251adc893695c119eb9653cd2 for http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/maven-archetype/2.2/maven-archetype-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected d5572e8bea6f4876a086779ea878d71731d0ab36 but is 0d9d945a1b1c11a251adc893695c119eb9653cd2 for http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/maven-archetype/2.2/maven-archetype-2.2.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/maven-archetype/2.2/maven-archetype-2.2.pom (15 KB at 36.9 KB/sec)
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:jar:2.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/2.2/maven-archetype-plugin-2.2.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/2.2/maven-archetype-plugin-2.2.jar (86 KB at 207.7 KB/sec)
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:jar:2.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar (165 KB at 381.1 KB/sec)
ε°⌡ 12, 2013 12:43:48 AM org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.Logs$JULSink warn
WARNING: Error injecting: org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/shared/invoker/MavenInvocationException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1855)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:629)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:831)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:758)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:255)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:204)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:954)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:987)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:950)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1000)
        at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:45)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:84)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
        at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.lifecycles.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:138)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:108)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:965)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1011)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:961)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:83)
        at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:253)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:245)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:455)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:92)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.MavenInvocationException
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
        ... 54 more

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.952s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 12 00:43:48 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/109M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate failed: A required class w
as missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate: org/apache/maven/shared/invoker/MavenInvocationException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/Oz/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/2.2/maven-archetype-plugin-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/Oz/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.MavenInvocationException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
C:\Users\Oz>
```

When I manually downloaded the problematic file from:
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/maven-archetype/2.2/maven-archetype-2.2.pom
I noticed that the file is not formatted well (I guess the XML should be valid and it isn't).

Is it a known bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: did you tried deleting local repo and download dependencies again?

Comment: Yes but it didn't help. After investigation it was a problem with my ISP.

Comment: I'm getting ISB Blocker error in pom files. Was it a credential problem or something else ? Can you remember that ?

Comment: No. My ISP used proxy for that page and for some reason the pom file was corrupted.